# Merge multiple binary files in Node.js

Tags: node.js, file

I want to merge sliced files into one, but I can't find a way to do so. I tried merge-files but it doesn't work for certain formats. I also tried to make my own but it ended up not working. So... how do I merge multiple (it can go up to thousands) binary files?

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered the issue -
basically you read all the files as buffers then concat them and write the result:

```
import * as fse from 'fs-extra';

function mergeExample(filePathsArray, outputFilePath) {
  let bufferArr = [];
  filePathsArray.forEach(file => {
    let currentFileBuffer = fse.readFileSync(file);
    bufferArr.push(currentFileBuffer);
  });
  let bufferConcat = Buffer.concat(bufferArr);
  fse.writeFileSync(outputFilePath, bufferConcat);
}
```

Comment: How do you parse / split this on the other end?

Comment: You need to know depending on what you use it for, if you need to split it I would use a special symbol and split it based on that symbol, or I wouldnt combine them in the first place I would zip them and send the zip file or something like that